# Error "Fatal: Could not read from remote repository" git push - ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, push

When I push my repo it throws me the message:

$ git push origin master
fatal: 'https // github.com / PanteraSama / landingPageResponsive.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Investigating I configured the ssh key on github,
But when I want to commit again it doesn't let me either.
can you help me?

Comment: Do you have access to the repository on GitHub?

Comment: Is that the exact URL you used?  In other words, you copied and pasted the output from your terminal into the question?

Comment: did you try to use ```git@github.com:PanteraSama/landingPageResponsive.git```

Comment: What does "ssh -T git@github.com" returns to you when you write it in terminal?

Comment: $ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi PanteraSama! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the output you've provided, your URL has spaces and is missing the colon after `https`.  As a result, Git thinks of this as a relative local path and tries to push to it, but fails because that path doesn't exist.

You would fix this by running the following:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/PanteraSama/landingPageResponsive.git
```

If you mistyped the output in your question and your URL is in fact correct in your code, then the likely issue is that this is a private repo and you don't have the proper credentials.  SSH keys are used only for SSH access and aren't used for HTTPS, which uses a username and password (or more securely, a username and token).

Comment: I changed the url, you're right, the url was wronge (https://) and the results is: $ git push origin master
remote: Permission to PanteraSama/landingPageResponsive.git denied to connietubio.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PanteraSama/landingPageResponsive.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
My repo is public

Comment: If you're getting a 403, your credentials are bad.  If you're using 2FA, you need to use a personal access token instead of your password.  You can search StackOverflow for 403 and GitHub and you should find answers to help you out.